# Android progress bar: Percentage is not shown

Tags: android, progress-bar

Sorry i am new in Android and have 2 questions about my progress bar:

1- I am going to create my progress bar something like [image] 
**Which style should i choose?**

2-Currently my progress bar doesn't show the percentage of progress? **Why?**

progress bar XML:

```
  <ProgressBar
         android:id="@+id/progressBar"
         style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
         android:layout_width="0dip"
         android:layout_height="100dp"
         android:padding="10dip"
         android:layout_margin="4dip"
         android:layout_weight="1"  />
```

Java code:

```
   mProgressBar = (ProgressBar)findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
   mProgressBar.setProgress(avg);
```

Comment: %of progress is not shown by ProgressBar in android. If you REALLY want it, you should create some animated views with a textView updtaed continuously.

Comment: have a look at http://suyu-android-dev.blogspot.in/2012/09/display-percentage-on-progressbar.html tutorial.