# How to make a ProgressBar not indeterminate in Android

Tags: android, progress-bar

I'm creating this ProgressBar, and I want it to show progress. It's really simple, it is just a percentage of 5000ms. My problem is whatever I try, the ProgressBar stays indeterminate (cyclic). Could anyone help me on this? Thanks.

Comment: Hmm... what function would I use for that again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Use This        

        ProgressDialog progressDialog=new ProgressDialog(this);
        progressDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
        progressDialog.setMessage("Loading....");
        progressDialog.setTitle("Please Wait");
        progressDialog.show();
```

To show Progress, here p is an int value

```
progressDialog.setProgress(p)
```

To cancel load

```
    progressDialog.cancel();
```

if You donot want hte title of Dialog

```
    progressDialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
```

Comment: Hmm... does it have to be a ProgressDialog?  I'm using a ProgressBar, so...

Comment: It is same for both

Comment: Either you use a ProgressBar or a ProgressDialog

Comment: Nope... they don't both work.

Comment: then use progressDialog,

Comment: If you are not getting it, you can see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16977009/android-progress-bar-percentage-is-not-shown

Comment: I need it to be a ProgressBar so that I'm able to hide it after it's done.

Comment: ProgressDialog is also hidable man

Comment: just use .show() or .cancel() to show or hide

Comment: Oh... in that case I'll try that.  How do I make a ProgressDialog?

Comment: ok i will give you the full code

Comment: see my edited answer